# Checking the origin in the HTTP header

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, supabase

I want to check the origin of the requests and compare it to my domain so that no one can change the data in my database except people on my site. I learned that you can write it via current_setting('request.headers.origin')

I asked ChatGPT to write me such a function, and this is what it gave me:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION rls_check(origin text)
RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN origin = 'https://******.netlify.app';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

a function that should return true or false, where the asterisks are my site name, everything is correct there, I took it from the header of the request.

```sql
CREATE POLICY my_table_policy ON my_table
   FOR ALL
   TO my_user
   USING (rls_check(current_setting('request.headers.origin')) = true);
```

this rule in RLS as, I don't really understand sql, but I think that everything is correct here too.

I added this code, tried different options, wrote manually, through sql editor nothing helps, I get a 404 error when sending or receiving a request.
I think it's the function itself, because when I wrote `RETURN true`
everything worked.

What am I doing wrong? What could be wrong? What other solutions do you know?

Thank you.

Comment: your problem is ,  that when you create a policy, it would be a row level policy, but you didn't secify which column must have the origin, you only check the origin is your app, but you must have rules that postgres can determine if a row is valid

Comment: @nbk this helped me
`current_setting('request.headers')::json ->> 'origin' = site_origin()`
site_origin() is a simple function that just returns a string, it acts as a variable for me. this function looks like this

`begin return 'https://mysite.netlify.app'; end`

Comment: i think you should read the manual about row level policies,  you get more hints what to look  for https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html